# Eval stacktrace with formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, stack-trace

I want to take an EventLog entry which has a stack trace in its Message and bind it to a GridView.  If I use Eval("Message") and put it in a label or a < p >, it displays, but the stack trace is smashed together.

If I Eval it in a TextBox, it keeps its formatting.

Is there a way to evaluate this stacktrace value to some sort of literal-type control and preserve formatting?

I've tried Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Message")) without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need to convert the newlines to HTML linebreaks.  Try something like this:

```
String htmlMessage = e.Message.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

Comment: It doesn't solve all of the indenting that was in place, but I know where to go from here.  Thanks!